# How to fix Swiper Js initial loading for a Carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, swiper.js

I am using the swiper js: https://idangero.us/swiper/api/  but the problem is
when used the initial loading shows the single carousel item first then remaining items starts showing up. Which behaves like a glitch.

Making is clearer. If i load the website i will only see the first item in the carousel (in the red box) then it will change to layout like in the image with 4 items.

I could find that if i set `max-width:25%;` that will fix the issue for this case. But if there are 2 items in the carousel per view that css code will fix the width 25%.

Is there any way to fix it? Please help

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the exact same issue using Angular Universal SSR.

Comment: We're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the point of the initialization function call to the point at which all images were downloaded.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      // ...
    })
});
```

Comment: We're tried this, but it's still loading slowly. The images appear instantly, but the JS is loading slowly for us. So to the user loading the page, all the slides are bunched up together, there's initially no pagination or prev/next arrow, etc. Then several seconds later, the slides spread apart and the pagination bullets and arrows appear.